# JS: resizable table

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Есть таблица:

```
<table class='container' border='0px' cellspasing='0px'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='files'>files</div>
        </td>
        <td>        
            <div class='editor'>
                <textarea class='e_t'></textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>thing</td>
        <td><div class='terminal'>terminal</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

...

.container{
    background: #3C3C3C;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}​

th, td {
   border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтоб когда наводишь курсор на обводку элемента таблицы, можно было подвинуть его в сторону. Например, как на JSFiddle.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только не уверен, что там таблица.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует плагин для jQuery, jquery-layout. [Демо](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html).

Comment: Классно! Сейчас попробую. А нет ли чего-нибудь без jQuery?